# Формы select в React

Tags: reactjs, form, html-select

Есть стандартная форма выбора страны-региона города. Хочу реализовать на реакте подгрузку нужных регионов в зависимости от выбора страны, но не понимаю как передать что было выбрано.

```
<select className="form-control-sm" id="select_loading">
    <InputLoad value={'by'} country={'Беларусь'} />
    <InputLoad value={'ru'} country={'Россия'} />
    <InputLoad value={'ua'} country={'Украина'} />
    <InputLoad value={'kz'} country={'Казахстан'} />                    
</select>

<select className="form-control-sm" id="select_loading">
    <InputLoad value={'by'} country={'Минская'} />
    <InputLoad value={'ru'} country={'Гомельская'} />
    <InputLoad value={'ua'} country={'Гродненская'} />
    <InputLoad value={'kz'} country={'Витебская'} />
</select>
```

Второй селект должен подгружатся в зависимости от выбора первого.

Вот компонент InputLoad:

```
function InputLoad(props) {
    return(
        <option value={props.value}>{props.country}</option>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

У дом элемента `select` есть событие `onchange` которое срабатывает при выборе элемента. Может это вам поможет.

```
<select onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>
```

Сам код:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: this.props.data[0] };
    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
  }

  onChangeHandler(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{ value }</h1>
        <select onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>
          { data.map(item => (
            <option key={item} value={item}>
              { item }
            </option>
          )) }
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App data={ [10,20,30,40,50] }/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Все конечно зависит от вашей модели данных, как будут лежать страны и города. Предположим, что это будет вложенный объект:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const json = [
  {
    country: "Country1",
    value: "value1",
    cities: [
      {
        city: "1 City1",
        value: "1 value1"
      },
      {
        city: "1 City2",
        value: "1 value2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    country: "Country2",
    value: "value2",
    cities: [
      {
        city: "2 City1",
        value: "2 value1"
      },
      {
        city: "2 City2",
        value: "2 value2"
      }
    ]
  }
]

function App() {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState();
  const [city, setCity] = useState();
  const data = json;
  const changeCountry = ({target: {value}}) => {
    setCountry(value);
    setCity("")
  }
  const changeCity = ({target: {value}}) => setCity(value);
  return (
    <>
      <p>Selected: {country} {city}</p>
      <select onChange={changeCountry} value={country}>
        {!country && <option/>}
        {data.map((c, i) => <option value={c.value} key={i}>{c.country}</option>)}
      </select>

      <select onChange={changeCity} value={city}>
        {!city && <option/>}
        {data.find(c => c.value === country) && 
          data.find(c => c.value === country).cities.map((c, i) => <option value={c.value} key={i}>{c.city}</option>)}
      </select>
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit quiet-cookies-izwxo]